# MySQL insert only if not exist in two tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a little problem with MySQL query. I'm using PDO queries, which now just insert values into the tables (see below):

```
$stmt = $dbh -> prepare("INSERT INTO tmp (user_id, test_id, question_id, answer_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt -> bindParam(1, $_SESSION['UserID']); // binds parameter for user id
$stmt -> bindParam(2, $_GET['start_test']); // binds parameter for test id
$stmt -> bindParam(3, $_POST['question']); // binds parameter for selected answer
$stmt -> bindParam(4, $_POST['select_answer']); // binds parameter for selected answer
$stmt -> execute();
```

`tmp` table structure is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `answer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I want to insert `answer_id` value if it's wasn't there and check if user_id at the same time, otherwise just update, example:

I have two users with user_id=1 and user_id=2, they're answering the questions and every answer for each student stores separately. User_id=1 picked answer_id = 3 and user_id=2 picked the answer_id = 3. However, then one user realised this was a wrong answer and wants to change it to another one (suppose answer_id=2), I want the query update the current answer_id=3 WHERE user_id=1 to answer_id=2

Answer (score 2):

You can make an `INSERT IGNORE` for the same, which looks simpler and will be atomic with some issues.

Step are like

1. Create a unique index on (user_id,question_id, answer_id)

   ALTER TABLE tmp add index user_qn_ans_idx (user_id,question_id, answer_id);
2. Now just do the insert, and probably on duplicate key update as well

   INSERT INTO tmp (user_id,question_id, answer_id) values 
   (, , )
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE answer_id = VALUES(answer_id)

Answer (score 0):

Add a select count and do conditionals below:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count( 1 ) FROM tmp WHERE user_id = :user_id AND question_id = :question_id and answer_id = :answer_id");
$stmt->bindValue( 'user_id', 1 );
$stmt->bindValue( 'question_id', 1 );
$stmt->bindValue( 'answer', 1 );
$stmt->execute();
$oExists = $stmt ->fetch();
if( !empty( $oExists ) )
{
// Run update sql...
}
else
{
// Run insert sql...
```

Comment: here I made some changes have a look I changed my code into the way you suggested, but now it always updates and not inserting new rows for some reason..

Answer (score 0):

```html
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count( 1 ) FROM tmp WHERE user_id = :user_id AND question_id = :question_id AND answer_id = :answer_id");
$stmt->bindValue( 'user_id', 1 );
$stmt->bindValue( 'question_id', 1 );
$stmt->bindValue( 'answer_id', 1 );
$stmt->execute();
$oExists = $stmt ->fetch();
 if( !empty( $oExists ) ) {
  echo "update";
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE tmp SET answer_id = :answer_id WHERE user_id = {$_SESSION['UserID']} AND question_id = {$_POST['question']}"); //updates the counter each time test created                                 
 $stmt -> bindParam(':answer_id', $_POST['select_answer'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $stmt -> execute();
 } else {
 echo "insert"; 
 $stmt = $dbh -> prepare("INSERT INTO tmp (user_id, test_id, question_id, answer_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
 $stmt -> bindParam(1, $_SESSION['UserID']); // binds parameter for user id
 $stmt -> bindParam(2, $_GET['start_test']); // binds parameter for test id
 $stmt -> bindParam(3, $_POST['question']); // binds parameter for selected answer
 $stmt -> bindParam(4, $_POST['select_answer']); // binds parameter for selected answer
 $stmt -> execute();
 }
```

Here is always updates, but not inserts..

Comment: That's because it is stubbed to always select user_id of 1, question_id of 1 and answer_id of 1. You need to pass those values in each time to make it dynamic $stmt->bindValue( 'user_id', $_SESSION['UserID'] );
$stmt->bindValue( 'question_id', $_POST['question'] );
$stmt->bindValue( 'answer_id', $_POST['select_answer'] );